# Having trouble styling my JQuery UI tabs in my Rails 4 app

Tags: css, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-tabs

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with the JQuery-UI plugin.  I have JQuery tabs, which are set up like so

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><%= link_to 'My Objects’, root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Lookup Results', search_times_objects_path %></li>
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation_links' %>
</ul>
</div>
```

and I would like to style selected tabs differently than unselected tabs, so I added this to my stylesheet …

```
ul.nav {
    font-family: 'russo_oneregular';
}
ul.tabs li.ui-state-active,ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-color: #000000;
}
ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-active a, ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected a {
    font-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Although the stylesheet is loaded, none of the tabs is styled, even when they are selected/unselected.  What do I need to adjust to get things to style properly?

**Edit:**To give some insight into what gets included, this is in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file ...

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery.modal
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .
```

which renders as

```
        <script src="/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-93be4d22eda916787802a64d8f88b52db8a9027d4ccbbc0942625324a7d12d44.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self-c1602241ddc51216b58391768667068867b8e15b9efc722befcd25771eda6819.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-c95f320275150a94241b004a91e21eef9c5ae9965a793cb3e2475f6078a1670d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.self-e693ced4ecfa1a276f0b794f32c1d30d792764b08788bf68ecfa3b388c291333.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/menu.self-7abc1c9401509a7e4fc609b1e461be6fd17e8116e8fda19cc59d05ba79aefb68.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.self-3befc48aba87cead090cfd014562b2771a662ac6d2c8197b24c08b2d9f3d9f2d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/button.self-4d4f21ba77bbf8cc08ae65e2b6329a7a1b952b32c3ba7bffca8313e7e8c93d0c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.self-6267be6d4d0f0e8665be3b4d6ac07f40ba23a32aff8eaa5d1bfc00f76a9eeae7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/mouse.self-c513294e8da73f31f84ba3ef11e2a1180a47faea0eb2fea4a53fc26153dd21fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.self-debcca3d0d5d9afe2fe91a6fd1aebdb41ca0a55f2f6017352e6c02b6d8a6e64c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.self-60b870565f3cd62982c1907828119bb51f42ec8228d5e23868153edc3abc685c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.self-5a6c7980dfa3f6b74445b0f4b20eed799ee65363163500ed7f032e603d6b022d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/droppable.self-a7a2b4c2cec8fc176f51e4e4291d92bfd3eec40b6a580b47fc54c16334d52882.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect.self-3acdb29e7da09c8f0195b994d2f04d73bfef50dc539c84fd2c835d964d33e5c1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-blind.self-ed102209d7aa0b7374f3db8478cc7dcff5f9980d3146e8bf9fbfab959c6d5d8a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-bounce.self-bfcb9288797ecd234ddeedf4fbc5b4c9de94a4e6d8d44e6faa5b5e9836fad9fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-clip.self-7368e4597c32360b162d264ff8bbd0cf9fb1535eb9b4564e6eb7c1db3c774bf3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-drop.self-294aaa72126ad9c94d6558cca792eb3716754713aca98f18a9dd7c493150ed92.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-explode.self-68e74dc114a52f3f4d7033e40c39196961bdcf439652daa2e98baa115c7bb44b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fade.self-42d542a5253e0a610717460102ee6bee339c656cc188e491d89eb0779043c963.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fold.self-ad9967f153423916300dbf1104b00f7ad7bbd6a222a0fcc1012ebe251bcb13c8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-highlight.self-f922b7179ab8ccfa7865141f38865bba0a3d2bdceba7561c27ca14544dbfd996.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-size.self-368aecefa09656a2be5c72dc8e685b120363a3df812134cbd2dd998bafa179fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-scale.self-884a5abcb6d90fcd9f9a071aa8329638184df688afced1b1d3b6be6c69f4dd7f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-puff.self-93415831093923a70f671d73e8d0b3d94deb37ac7472a036a4add545f565c166.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-pulsate.self-eb107c0d136eccdfbd8a2f0f2ee71e0f6911cb300c6b63cc2fe4f6532e6a9a97.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-shake.self-63bcc14897aac5b84e10690be94d64d5724f864aa14c913b4d1030c461a256ad.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-slide.self-c93054a4a80d1f986760806d81ab067e4a4120bf103337e152ecc24d36e785f6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-transfer.self-181245634ec522320fc1081f6dbf94fd982f34eefa03555f76817dedfcdea336.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/progressbar.self-a259ff5a2a5e7aef0ec21bda94edd0f6bc1e9821128d901de415956edf212b0d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectable.self-42e53fc2f95211314e36a8094c42560f869c207f16d68cfc206aa37201dcdc03.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectmenu.self-09dbcac573f0e508194bd9deff254db090889b380d030261857860309c0918e8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/slider.self-8af8d2a0661743ba88b4cfb99d5c8c874cfa3fc6528ae4e9252366b388def0b7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.self-df2d80a36f9dfbe0facc596ccd92af83ca50d38e4cd6a84810aaf5d40b8cd181.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/spinner.self-3c8c95a7bc9c877d0f9c16789246bbedda6b8e8fbf5927951babdab775aed02e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.self-dc07b44bf1b926c8d28ccd2658e30933881e5329348caf70cf305c3943f6bbd7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tooltip.self-38f04ac3a6c8fb2391ec6832b68845671cc9013a94371b7eb239478f4835eb73.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.self-52111578aa54225c9ebfe06f78a62771020ee548bb27d62228ee3f5e6633969d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.modal.self-c79a0f0d30a0d56ed5ef3e848fb327eaf0347b19edc3e32a4ed01ab7981e124c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/my_objects.self-b0b6ec46f1eff3cf4f5a976553214f42f58a748ce51e756f9f238e136d41e30a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/user_my_object_time_matches.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.self-abf55f804796de5da127bcfc5fb78b0494e1e0968b014300c8b6ae359f4a19ad.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
        <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that from this `ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-active a, ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected a` it seems that you are looking for `ul.tabs` or `<ul class="tabs"></ul>` but you have `<ul class="nav">`

Try

```
ul.nav li.ui-state-active,ul.nav li.ui-tabs-selected { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-color: #000000;
}
ul.nav li.ui-tabs-active a, ul.nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
    font-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Also, make sure that tabs are initialized:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I cut and pasted your code into my stylesheet (replacing what was there previously) but no dice.  It is almost as if the "ui-state-active" and "ui-tabs-active" styles are not activated when I click on the tabs or otherwise render the page.

Comment: YOur update is just including the initialization of the tabs?  I had already been doing that but even still the styles aren't appearing upon selection/de-selection.  When I inspect the selected tab, the element in Chrome is listed as "ul.nav li a" (there is no "ui-tabs-selected" portion of the element anywhere I can see)

Comment: Please read the implementation details carefully: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ . It seems that you have made your links with redirect which does not work for tabs. See the samples provided in the documentation

Comment: I have read this whole article multiple times but I dont' see anything about forbidding redirects when you click on a tab.  Even if that is true, the first time the page is loaded, one tab is selected and the rest are not, so in that situation we should see the appropriate styles (before anything is clicked) but I do not.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer you should change `ul.tabs` to `ul.nav`.
And then there is no `font-color` CSS property, it should be [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color).

Below is a demo with your CSS in effect:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

```css
ul.nav {
  font-family: 'russo_oneregular';
}
ul.nav li.ui-state-active,
ul.nav li.ui-tabs-selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
ul.nav li.ui-tabs-active a,
ul.nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed "font-color" to "color" but no dice.  I'm noticing that when your page loads, the first tab is automatically selected (and your li includes the class "ui-tabs-tab ui-state-default ui-tab ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active").  My li class includes nothing.  How do those classes get assigned to the tab right out of the gate?  There are no JS errors on my page and I do see the tabs rendered.  Is RoR screwing with the page in some way?

Comment: @Dave Do you have jQuery included followed by jQuery UI? It's jQuery UI who adds the classes when we do `$("#tabs").tabs();`. So that script should run when DOM is ready. Also you shouldn't be loading jQuery twice or have conflicting versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with RoR but if you can share the generated HTML page source then I can take a look at it and find what's wrong

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have these things (I can also type "$('#tabs')" in my console to validate taht jquery is on the page and working.  I have included the JS that Rails renders. I see a "tabs" and "jqueyr-ui" in there, but not sure why Rails adds all that extra stuff.

Comment: If you have all that, and the script is executed after DOM is ready like `$(function() {})` there it's strange. Do you have something else with a tabs plugin like bootstrap in page?

Comment: Hi, No there is no bootstrap.  When the jQuery ".tabs" function is invoked, how does JQuery know which is the selected tab?  Maybe I'm not including the correct meta-data here to indicate to JQuery what the appropriate tab shoudl be.

Comment: @Dave s your DOM structure similar to what I have in the demo? it selects the first tab by default. Maybe you should put the entire generated page source in something like pastebin so that we can check what is wrong??

Comment: The big difference in the structure is that in your anchor links, you have "#tab-1" whereas my links are actual links to other pages (e.g. href="/page2").  I think this is the root of the issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  As I am the eternal optimist, I'm going to keep searching around for a solution (or some hack work-around) to this but thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dave I don't think you'll get any help unless you share the sample of generated code. We are in a black box. For example I just came to know you have some kind of weird routing after asking all these questions. God knows what else. You need to share a [mcve] if you're looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

1) Do the `<li>` tags show the correct class in your console?
2) Are you sure your stylesheet is loaded?
3) As mentioned, use `color`, not `font-color`.
4) Looking at the jquery-ui example, it seems like `li.ui-tabs-selected` is selected from outside the `ul`, what might overwrite your css rules, especially if you load your css before jquery-ui.css

```
#tabs ul.tabs li.ui-state-default {
    /* test */
    color: red !important;
}
#tabs ul.tabs li.ui-state-active,
#tabs ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000000;
}
#tabs ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-active a, 
#tabs ul.tabs li.ui-tabs-selected a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```